# Cost of referencing "window.[height/width/etc]" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been struggling to find a definitive answer as to whether or not referencing `window.height/width/something` repeatedly is something that can affect performance in website loading times.

I've got some React components that reference `window.height` and `window.width` in state (without a resize listener), and I'm wondering if it makes more sense to pass down `window` dimensions from some parent component in order to improve performance.

I'm guessing it won't really make a difference for several components to be referencing `window` dimensions when the site loads rather than a single one, but that's just a guess.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's always a bad idea to poll repeatedly. There will be some cost. And it's good practice to let your components react to the change rather than poll for it.

Try rxJs Observable fromEvent

```
Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize')
        .debounceTime(1500)
        .subscribe((event) => {
          this.doSmth(event);
        });
```